# Detectar codificacion de txt

Tags: c#, utf-8, codificación

Buen dia, he buscado la forma de obtener mediante una aplicacion de C# la codificacion de un archivo de texto plano pero no he podido encontrar algo concreto ¿alguno sabe como realizar lo que busco?

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar un [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader) para detectar la codificación de un archivo de texto leyendo su propiedad [`CurrentEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding).

Según la documentación, la detección automática de la codificación se realizará cuando llames a la función [`Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read). Así que es necesario llamarla antes de leer la propiedad `CurrentEnconding`.

Según esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393739/13419694), también es válido usar la función [`Peek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.peek?view#system-io-streamreader-peek).